# Safecracker related(?) error: "Unable to load the requested language"

Tags: safecracker, system-messages

I'm using a safecracker form for guests to submit entries. When I'm logged out and I visite the page with the safecrackerform I get this error thrown at me:

"Unable to load the requested language file: language/dutch/upload_lang.php"

This happens also when I change the language settings in the general config to English. The member_id to use for guests also uses English settings.
The upload_lang.php file I can only find in system > codeigniter > system > language > english.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing a language pack, looks like there's one for Dutch
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/languages.html

You could also try copying the upload_lang.php file from another langauge directory and modify it to translate the text to Dutch. But I would try the lang packs first.

Comment: I've got the Dutch pack installed already, there is no "upload_lang.php" in neither the Dutch nor English pack. Meanwhile I've taken another road (comments) for user input.

Answer (score 0):

The upload_lang.php is being asked for somewhere so try creating an empty php file named "upload_lang.php" and place it in the dutch language directory. That should get rid of the error.